# How To Change Math Font Only?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'd like to keep my text in Helvetica as usual but would like to have my equations and formulas in Roman or MT Extra. So far, I've tried using different packages but that changes both the text and the math. I'm writing my document using LaTeX.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First select the package that changes the math font and the text font, such as

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

And *then* change the text font.

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{hpv}% or whatever
```

Comment: The codename for Helvetica is "phv" ("p" for postscript (adobe) and "hv" for helvetica).

Comment: @Philippe: Oh! I always wondered about the strange names.