# How does one change the math font size?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to scale math font only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only)

Similar to [how to change math font only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/how-to-change-math-font-only), is there a way to change the size of fonts in math formulas?

**EDIT -- DUPLICATE OF [how to scale math font only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only)**

Comment: I recommend to use `\DeclareMathSizes`. Have a look at [Size of math equations in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/size-of-math-equations-in-latex) and [how to scale math font only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only) for further explanation.

Comment: So I guess we should close this as a duplicate, right?

Comment: @Hendrik: Right. :-)

Answer (score 5):

By using the commands

- `\displaystyle`
- `\textstyle`
- `\scriptstyle`
- `\scriptscriptstyle`

Comment: This does more than just scaling the math font. And it doesn't allow you to set arbitrary sizes.

Comment: It is however mighty practical for a one-shot change (e.g. a few symbols in a matrix).