# Arrow with plus/minus sign on top

Tags: symbols

Below you can see an arrow with a plus and a minus sign on top of it. How is this achievable in latex? Further possibilities: arrow with only plus and arrow with only minus sign on top. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Is `$\xrightarrow{+/-}$` (or `$\xrightarrow{+}$` or `$\xrightarrow{-}$`) what you want? You can use one of the commands [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9725/35864) to make the plus/minus sign smaller.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### `\stackrel`

LaTeX provides `\stackrel` to place something on a relational operator:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  A \stackrel{+/-}\longrightarrow
  B \stackrel{+}\rightarrow
  C \stackrel{-}\rightarrow
  D
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \stackrel]

- However the arrow is too short for the first case with `+/-`.
- The plus/minus signs are perfectly horizontally centered, but it does not look too good because of the arrow tip. The plus/minus signs should be moved to the left a little.

### `\xrightarrow`

Package `amsmath` addresses the previous problems by providing extensible arrows:

```
\xrightarrow[<below>]{<above>}
```

The length of the arrow grows with width of the annotations below or above.
The arrow tip is taken into account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ A \xrightarrow{+/-} B \xrightarrow{+} C \xrightarrow{-} D \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \xrightarrow]

But there is room for improvement:

- The minus and plus sign start and end with a horizontal line, thus the extra space of the arrow to the left and right can be reduced a little.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\rightarrowpm}[1]{%
  \xrightarrow{\!#1\!}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
   A \rightarrowpm{+/-}
   B \rightarrowpm{+}
   C \rightarrowpm{-}
   D
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \xrightarrow and !]

If the size of the plus and minus signs are too large, then `\scriptscriptstyle` can be added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\rightarrowpm}[1]{%
  \xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle\!#1\!}%                     
}

\begin{document}
\[
   A \rightarrowpm{+/-}
   B \rightarrowpm{+}
   C \rightarrowpm{-}
   D
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \xrightarrow + \, + \scriptscriptstyle]

### Scalable `\xrightarrow`

`\xrightarrow` of `amsmath` does not resize automatically with different math styles. The last example redefines `\ext@arrow` for `\rightarrowpm` to make it scalable according to the current math style. A smaller style than `\scriptscriptstyle` is achieved by scaling to 90%.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rightarrowpm}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\ext@arrow\ext@arrow@scalable
    \xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle\!#1\!}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\ext@arrow@scalable}[7]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette{\@ext@arrow@scalable{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@ext@arrow@scalable}[8]{%
  \mathop{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#5#8}%
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{%
      \m@th
      \ifx#8\scriptscriptstyle
        \let\my@hbox\hbox@scriptscriptscaled
      \else
        \let\my@hbox\hbox@math
      \fi
      \my@hbox{%
        \ifx#8\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi
        \mkern#3mu{#6}\mkern#4mu%
      }%
      \my@hbox{%
        \ifx#8\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi
        \mkern#3mu{#7}\mkern#4mu%
      }%
      \copy\z@
    }%
    \hbox to\wd\tw@{\unhbox\z@}}%
  \limits
    \@ifnotempty{#7}{%
      ^{%
        \ifx#8\scriptscriptstyle
          \expandafter\hbox@scriptscriptscaled
        \else
          \expandafter\@firstofone
        \fi
        {%
          \if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
          #7%
          \if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \@ifnotempty{#6}{%
      _{%
        \ifx#8\scriptscriptstyle
          \expandafter\hbox@scriptscriptscaled
        \else
          \expandafter\@firstofone
        \fi
        {%
          \if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
          #6%
          \if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi
        }%
      }%
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\hbox@scriptscriptscaled}[1]{%
  \hbox{%
    \scalebox{.9}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1\m@th$}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\hbox@math}[1]{%
  \hbox{$#1\m@th$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \rightarrowpm{+/-} B^{A\rightarrowpm{+/-}B^{A\rightarrowpm{+/-}B}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thx! It works. Can you tell me what \\[...\\] means?

Comment: @tester: `\[...\]` are used for unnumbered displayed equations, see ["The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Package `amsmath` provides `\overset` to put something over a binary or relational operator:

```
\overset{+/-}{\longrightarrow}
```

[image]

Comment: Could the downvoter please add a _reason_ for this?

Comment: @JosephWright: Possible (I have not voted) reasons: (1) Package `amsmath` is missing that provides `\overset`. (2) The annotation above the arrow exceeds the arrow width. (3) The size of the symbols above the arrow might be too large.

Comment: I don't know but I upvoted you :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer an auto-size solution, use `amsmath`'s `\xrightarrow{}`.

```
$\xrightarrow{+/-}$
```

If you want smaller +/- signs you can use `$\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle +/-}$`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\xrightarrow{+/-}$
$\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle +/-}$

$\xrightarrow{+}$
$\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle +}$
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]