# How to draw change-of-coordinates notation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

For a homework assignment, I'd like to include something like the following image in my document as a single term in an equation:
[image: Desired output]

I know I could simply use another variable name, but my professor prefers this notation. My main problem is placing the P above the B \leftarrow C; is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you use `\stackrel` as in [Arrow with plus/minus sign on top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134523)?

Comment: You also (in case what's over the arrow might be large) `\xleftarrow{P}`, an extensible arrow.