# How do I get the concrete font for math only?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Is there a package that loads the concrete font, but only for the math, not for the normal text?

Comment: Please have a look at this site: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [How To Change Math Font Only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/how-to-change-math-font-only) as a guide, here's what you can do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http;//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{ccfonts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{ccfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.or/pkg/fontenc
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}% cmr = Computer Modern Roman
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\gamma f=\sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\mathrm{Res}(f;a_k) \label{eq}
\end{equation}
Take a look at $n(\gamma;a_k)$ in~\eqref{eq}.
\end{document}
```

Note that inline (or text style) and display math both use Concrete, while the equation numbers are set in Computer Modern.

The idea is, as mentioned in the linked post, you set the entire font change, and revert `\rmdefault` back to the font of your choice - `cmr` (or Computer Modern Roman) in this case.

If you're using other type face families, like `\textsf` and `\texttt`, these have to be modified (reverted as well):

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}% cmtt = Computer Modern Typewriter
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}% cmss = Computer Modern Sans-Serif
```

Answer (score 12):

The `Concrete Roman` font is a pure *text* font; unlike `Computer Modern`, there's no built-in math font in this family. The textbook *Concrete Mathematics* authored by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik used (unsurprisingly) the `Concrete Roman` text font along with the `Euler` math font family.

To employ the `Euler` math font family, you could load the [eulervm](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/eulervm) package.

Answer (score 9):

You can save the default font families before loading `ccfonts` and then restore them; load any other font package before the code marked "save defaults". In this way you don't need to know what names have the three main font families.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%%% save defaults
\edef\keptrmdefault{\rmdefault}
\edef\keptsfdefault{\sfdefault}
\edef\keptttdefault{\ttdefault}

\usepackage{ccfonts}

%%% restore defaults
\edef\rmdefault{\keptrmdefault}
\edef\sfdefault{\keptsfdefault}
\edef\ttdefault{\keptttdefault}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant*[1]
\[
a+b=\sin\alpha+e^{\beta}-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]