# Codename for "kp serif" in TeX

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, kpfonts

mainly i'm aiming at doing the same thing as discussed in this question ([How To Change Math Font Only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/how-to-change-math-font-only)); except i want to use the "km serif" font and no matter what i search for on the web, i don't find the code to enter in the ”\renewcommand”-command. Is there one and if there isn't, how could i work around it? I do love the kp serif font but the math mode version of it just looks completely bonkers - i'd rather want to use the garamond font if thats possible using pdfLaTeX - if it isn't i'd probably use Computer Modern Bright.

Thanks for reading my question, perhaps you can answer it?

Greetings

Comment: I think it's `jkpss`.

Comment: Probably `jkp`. I'm guessing `ss` is sans.

Comment: Is `\usepackage[nomath]{kpfonts}` what you want? It loads all the text fonts, but does not modify mathematical fonts. In any case, if you need to use the low-level commands, the font names for this purpose are listed in Section 5.1 of the [`kpfonts` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/kpfonts).

Comment: @PaulGessler Turn it into an answer? ;-) I would, however, include the original answer and how you got to it (if you have it). It's probably good practice to avoid work-arounds as much as possible (you might find a meta post on this soon).

Comment: @1010011010 I will convert to an answer if the OP confirms that this is actually what he wants/needs. And: What original answer? Is this a dupe?

Comment: @PaulGessler The answer to the actual question. E.g. the non-workaround solution. I don't think workarounds are the right way to answer a question, even if they're green ticked by the OP.

Comment: @1010011010 well, depending on what the actual question _is_, changing `\rmdefault` might not be a workaround but the actual answer. He only mentioned KP serif, but what about KP sans? KP mono? We have no idea if he wants these changed too, or only the serif. Hence why I wait for input from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`kpfonts` has a `nomath` option for precisely this purpose. It will load all Kepler text fonts, but not modify any mathematics fonts.

The `\usepackage[math]{blindtext}` and `\blindmathpaper` in the example are just for some sample text with mathematics; they are not needed for your actual document.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomath]{kpfonts} % load kpfonts without modifying maths fonts
\usepackage[math]{blindtext} % just for sample text with mathematics
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]